# How can I get neovim to return the cursor to the original line after formatting the file?

Tags: neovim

In order to solve the file formatting problem of vim, I simply wrote a function:

```
function FileFormat()
    let cursorLine = col(".")
    let filetype = &filetype
    if filetype == 'json'
        %!jq .
        execute cursorLine
    elseif filetype == 'cpp'
        %!astyle --style=attach --pad-oper --lineend=linux -N -C -L -xw -xW -w
        execute cursorLine
    else
        echo "Formatting of " . filetype  . " files is not currently supported."
    endif
endfunction
```

And map a shortcut key for this function:

```
:nnoremap <C-f> :call FileFormat()<cr>
```

But I found that after formatting the file, the cursor is still at the beginning of the line. I know this is because the cursor disappears when neovim enters command mode, causing the col() function to not get a valid line number.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

neovim version: 0.6.1

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I use the wrong function, I should not use the `col` function, I should get the cursor line number through `line(".")`, this function will not be affected by the mode switch.